# Find and replace string containing ' (apostrophes) in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

### Background

So I am writing an emotify script for my tumblr, so that when I am writing a post and write say ":)" it will APPEAR to be a smiley face, but as a matter of fact, if i edit the post, it is still an ":)".

I am very very extremely new to javascript (as well as this forum), but managed to make a script THAT I ACTUALLY UNDERSTAND!! I understand the method could be a lot easier using `jquery`, guessing its a branch of javascript, but I have looked into it and it's too hard to understand.

### Question

The script works all well and good until I want to replace ":'(" or "=.='" because of the apostrophe. I have searched high and low, tried very hard to make it work but alas, couldnt come up with anything. please if anyone has an ideas, it would be much appreciated.

```
function getElementsByClass(node,searchClass,tag) {
    var classElements = new Array();
    var els = node.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    var elsLen = els.length;
    var pattern = new RegExp("\\b"+searchClass+"\\b");
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < elsLen; i++) {
        if ( pattern.test(els[i].className) ) {
            classElements[j] = els[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return classElements;
}

function Smile() {

    var emoticons=new Array();
    emoticons[1]=" :)";
    emoticons[2]=" :D";
    emoticons[3]=" :(";
    emoticons[4]=" :'(";
    emoticons[5]=" XD";
    emoticons[6]=" :3";
    emoticons[7]=" :P";
    emoticons[8]=" ;)";
    emoticons[9]=" :S";
    emoticons[10]=" =.='";
    emoticons[11]=" o.O";
    emoticons[12]=" ^^";
    emoticons[13]=" :O";
    emoticons[14]=" =.=";

    var shortcuts=new Array();
    shortcuts[1]="http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/97bluwnkt/_.png";
    shortcuts[2]="http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/JNgluhdyn/d.png";
    shortcuts[3]="http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/Jaeluhq32/_.png";
    shortcuts[4]="http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/0mglujqan/__.png";
    shortcuts[5]="http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/JAkluhgto/xd.png";
    shortcuts[6]="http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/kEDluhdzu/3.png";
    shortcuts[7]="http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/UEnlug0o7/p.png";
    shortcuts[8]="http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/gkKlug0ow/wink.png";
    shortcuts[9]="http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/24iluhgu5/s.png";
    shortcuts[10]="http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/ieIluhp7m/__.png";
    shortcuts[11]="http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/oucluuvif/oo.png";
    shortcuts[12]="http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/blGluhwqw/__.png";
    shortcuts[13]="http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/ci0luwnbw/o.png";
    shortcuts[14]="http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/ieIluhp7m/__.png";

    var classes=new Array();
    classes[1]="body hasMarkup";
    classes[2]="caption hasMarkup";
    classes[3]="description hasMarkup";
    classes[4]="description";
    classes[5]="reply hasMarkup";
    classes[6]="caption";

    for (var counter = 1; counter < emoticons.length; counter++) {  
        var find = emoticons[counter];
        var repl = (' <img src="'+shortcuts[counter]+'">');
        for (var classcounter = 1; classcounter < classes.length; classcounter++) { 
            var myEls = getElementsByClass(document,classes[classcounter],'*');
            for ( v = 0; v < myEls.length; v++ ){
                var page = myEls[v].innerHTML;
                while (page.indexOf(find) >= 0) {
                    var i = page.indexOf(find);
                    var j = find.length;
                    page = page.substr(0,i) + repl + page.substr(i+j);
                    myEls[v].innerHTML = page;
                }                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code looks a lot neater in real life. please believe me. not sure how to format it nicely on this site. thanks in advance for your help.

### updated question!!

it is infact not the code that is malfunctioning, but because the apostrophes do not match. This is the apostrophe that tumblr spits out AND THAT I CANNOT CHANGE: ’
this is the apostrophe that is in the code: '

if i try to use the tumblr apostrophe in my js code, it destroys everything. all hell breaks loose. not to mention it doesnt work.

SO IS THERE A GLOBAL APOSTROPHE THAT WORKS ON EVERYTHING? or replaces all. that kinda stuff. and preferably wont break my code. thanks again. :)

thanks for all the replies. you guys are brilliant. :)

### update 2

i did determine that the tumblr apostrophe has an ascii code of #8217 whilst my javascript code uses #39
but i dont know how i can use this to modify and compatify my script.

### question has been resolved!!

many thanks to everyone who replied and responded. :)
especially Adam Jurczyk.

Comment: Did you know, you can use array literals? `var emoticons=[":)",":D",...]`

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Your script works fine for me, and has no problems with :'( or =.='

Comment: Even better, object (hash map) literals: `var emoticonMap = { ' :)': 'http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/97bluwnkt/_.png', ' :D': 'another_url', ... };`

Comment: @socha23, it just skips over the ones with apostrophes, like has no effect.@adam, yea i know. i prefer this method cuz it is easier on the eyes. XD@divad, no idea what you are on about...
im guessing maps is another javascript function i have yet to learn. i will look into it.

Comment: Just tried it and it works fine with apostrophes

Comment: @VinceAu, 'easier on the eyes'?! No, its not, trust me;] BTW, try to reproduce your problem on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) - maybe you find bug while rewriting it and we could all tinker with it a little :)

Comment: Unrelated word of advice - If you're going to work a lot with JavaScript, i highly recommend learning jQuery. It really does make things a -lot- easier and your coding more efficient once you get it, and trust me, it's not hard to learn, in fact it's oftentimes a lot easier than trying to reinvent the wheel yourself.

Comment: @andrewas: i know. i intend on learning jquery. but i want to know javascript first. i know it will help a lot.
guys i have pinpointed the error. it didn't replace because the apostrophe is differnt. i remember this happens fairly often especially when coding, and after a copy pasta, i always need to replace the apostrophes. because the apostrophes were different, it wouldnt replace.
so i copied the apostrophe from tumblr it self and pasted it into the emoticon array. as soon as i did that, it just broke my code. destroyed it completetly.
javascript does not like foreign apostrophes... :S

Comment: is there like a "global apostrophe"? one that works and is common to all things and works cross platform kinda thing?
cuz i could really use one... XD
thanks for the replies btw. i was scared i would only get unhelpful troll replies. :')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something simpler:

```
var emots = {
    " :)" : "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/97bluwnkt/_.png",
    " :D" : "https://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/JNgluhdyn/d.png",
    " :(" : "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/Jaeluhq32/_.png",
    " :'(" : "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/0mglujqan/__.png",
    " XD" : "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/JAkluhgto/xd.png",
    " :3" : "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/kEDluhdzu/3.png",
    " :P" : "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/UEnlug0o7/p.png",
    " ;)" : "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/gkKlug0ow/wink.png",
    " :S" : "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/24iluhgu5/s.png",
    " =.='" : "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/ieIluhp7m/__.png",
    " o.O" : "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/oucluuvif/oo.png",
    " ^^" : "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/blGluhwqw/__.png",
    " :O" : "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/ci0luwnbw/o.png",
    " =.=" : "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/ieIluhp7m/__.png"
};

function smile(str){
    var out = str;
    for(k in emots){
        out = out.replace(k,'<img src="'+emots[k]+'"/>','g');
    }
    return out;
}
```

Try it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uQmLL/1/) - works fine. Sometimes there is just no need for regexp magic [image]

**edit**

As for this apostrophes problem - try to find out what codepoint this tumblr apostrophe has (check 'see also' section for standard apos [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27/index.htm) and in emots for replace, use it instead - like here: `" :\u0027("`

**response from vince**

not sure what a codepoint is, but i did determine that the tumblr apostrophe has an ascii code of #8217 whilst my javascript code uses #39
i dont know how i can use this to modify and compatify my script.

**AJ:** JS literal for [#8217](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm) is `\u2019` so use it like this:

```
var emots = {
    //...
    " :\u2019(" : "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/0mglujqan/__.png",
```

Comment: Again, please refer to the above comment(s). it is infact not the code that is malfunctioning, but because the apostrophes do not match. This is the apostrophe that tumblr spits out AND THAT I CANNOT CHANGE. ’ this is the apostrophe that is in the code. ' if i try to use the tumblr apostrophe in my js code, it destroys everything. all hell breaks loose. not to mention it doesnt work.
again thanks for ur replies. and again with my previous question, IS THERE A GLOBAL APOSTROPHE THAT WORKS ON EVERYTHING? or replaces all. that kinda stuff. and preferably wont break my code. thanks again. :)

Comment: and wow. your code is really simple....
not sure what regexp is. but i will sort of need to change that code to work only in specific div classes. again thanks for the answer and see if you can answer the question in the previous comment. cheers.

Comment: [regexp = Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). The code above is only a plain function - how and where you get input for it, its up to you :)

Comment: ah i see.
not sure what a codepoint is, but i did determine that the tumblr apostrophe has an ascii code of #8217 whilst my javascript code uses #39
i dont know how i can use this to modify and compatify my script

Comment: Editing posts is BAD way for replies ;]

Comment: eek. my bad. :S
new to forum. dont ban me or whatever. :S
i will give it a shot now. thanks for your response. :)

Comment: that worked bloody brilliantly. thank you so much for your help!! :D
hold up. let me figure out how to +rep someone. XD
thank you so much again! :)
props to you good sir.
seems like i cant vote up til i get 15 rep...
whatever. how do i close a question? XD

Answer (score 0):

When I try to replace emoticons containing apostrophes, it works just fine.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/EQKzq/1/

Some notes on the code:

- Arrays are zero based, but you start using them at index 1.
- You can use the literal array syntax to initialise the arrays instead of putting one item at a time in the array.
- You can use the `push` method to add items to an array (in the `getElementsByClass` function).
- You put the content back in the element after each replacement, but you should do that after the loop.
- You should swap your loops so that you have the emoticon loop inside the element loop, that way you drastically reduce the number of times that you use `innerHTML`.

Updated code:

```
function getElementsByClass(node, searchClass, tag) {
  var classElements = [];
  var els = node.getElementsByTagName(tag);
  var elsLen = els.length;
  var pattern = new RegExp("\\b" + searchClass + "\\b");
  for (i = 0; i < elsLen; i++) {
    if (pattern.test(els[i].className)) {
      classElements.push(els[i]);
    }
  }
  return classElements;
}

function Smile() {
  var emoticons = [
    " :)",
    " :D",
    " :(",
    " :'(",
    " XD",
    " :3",
    " :P",
    " ;)",
    " :S",
    " =.='",
    " o.O",
    " ^^",
    " :O",
    " =.="
  ];
  var shortcuts = [
    "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/97bluwnkt/_.png",
    "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/JNgluhdyn/d.png",
    "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/Jaeluhq32/_.png",
    "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/0mglujqan/__.png",
    "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/JAkluhgto/xd.png",
    "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/kEDluhdzu/3.png",
    "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/UEnlug0o7/p.png",
    "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/gkKlug0ow/wink.png",
    "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/24iluhgu5/s.png",
    "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/ieIluhp7m/__.png",
    "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/oucluuvif/oo.png",
    "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/blGluhwqw/__.png",
    "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/ci0luwnbw/o.png",
    "http://static.tumblr.com/vyvljow/ieIluhp7m/__.png"
  ];
  var classes = [
    "body hasMarkup",
    "caption hasMarkup",
    "description hasMarkup",
    "description",
    "reply hasMarkup",
    "caption"
  ];
  for (var classcounter = 0; classcounter < classes.length; classcounter++) {
    var myEls = getElementsByClass(document, classes[classcounter], '*');
    for (v = 0; v < myEls.length; v++) {
      var page = myEls[v].innerHTML;
      var replaced = false;
      for (var counter = 0; counter < emoticons.length; counter++) {
        var find = emoticons[counter];
        var j = find.length;
        var repl = ' <img src="' + shortcuts[counter] + '">';
        do {
          var i = page.indexOf(find);
          if (i != -1) {
            replaced = true;
            page = page.substr(0, i) + repl + page.substr(i + j);
          }
        } while (i != -1);
      }
      if (replaced) {
          myEls[v].innerHTML = page;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry didnt see the answer:
this is from my comment above:
it didn't replace because the apostrophe is different. i recall this happens fairly often especially when coding, and after a copy pasta, i always need to replace the apostrophes.
so i copied the apostrophe from tumblr itself and pasted it into the emoticon array. as soon as i did that, it just broke my code. destroyed it completetly. javascript does not like foreign apostrophes.
is there like a "global apostrophe"? one that works and is common to all things and works cross platform kinda thing? cuz i could really use one...

Comment: also thanks for the answer.
i understand it is a lot more efficient but i no longer understand what is happening... what is the boolean replaced actually doing? im trying to slowly understand it. XD
!= means not equal to right? o.O
and what exactly is this line doing?
page = page.substr(0, i) + repl + page.substr(i + j);
again thanks for the reply and your patience. muchly appreciated. :)

Comment: The booelan `replaced` just keeps track of whether the value in `page` has changed or not, so we know if we have to write it back to the element. The `innerHTML` property is quite expensive, so it's worth it to minimise the usage. The line that changes the `page` variable is the same as in your original code; it does the actual replacement from the emoticon text (e.g. `:P`) to the image tag.